# Can I use the Idol during other player's turns?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

If I have the Idol in Betrayal at House on the Hill, can I use it on someone else's turn, say in a defensive roll? Or is it just for your turn? If I used it on someone else's turn can I also use it on my turn?

The text states:

> Once per turn...

And doesn't specify which turn. Should it say round?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No. Idol is an item, and may only be used on your own turn.**

From the [FAQ at wizards](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=ah/faqs/hoth#itemcards)

> **Can you use an item card outside of your turn (for instance, when you were attacked)?**
>
> The only items you could use outside your own turn are the Angel Feather, the Lucky Stone, and the omen Skull.