# How does the bloodstone work?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill, betrayal-widows-walk

I just lost a game with the villain using the bloodstone on everyone else's turn as well as there own to power up their rolls. How is that card supposed to be used. It says once per turn but doesn't specify the players turn or not.

Comment: Can you please post the text of the item so that people don't have to look it up to help you.

Comment: Do the rules say that you can use these cards on every turn, or only on your own?

Comment: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/8277/can-i-use-the-idol-during-other-players-turns

Answer (score 2):

Assuming bloodstone is an *item* or *omen*, the traitor used this incorrectly. Items are explicitly listed as being usable “once during your turn”. Some confusion may arise from the fact that later in that same section ([Rulebook](https://media.wizards.com/2018/downloads/rules/betrayal_rules.pdf), page 11), it lists the five potential things that you can do with an item (use, trade, drop, steal, pick up), only one of which you can do a turn. While this does not explicitly state *your* turn, it can be inferred from the section.  Also, on page 6, “Use item and omen cards” is listed under a heading of “ON YOUR TURN...”.

I could not find the rules for the Widow's Walk expansion online, but I don't recall them changing this aspect of item use.

Comment: Yeah bloodstone is an omen that is used as a weapon. This question is about haunt 67, Murderball

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Does Haunt 67 have any special rules for the traitor's use of items/omens/the bloodstone in particular?

Comment: it does indeed! Haunt 67 is pretty unique in the fact that everyone is the traitor, the bloodstone passes from player to player and must be used as a weapon to kill other players, in a game of murderous tag.

Comment: It sounds like that might not be the haunt in question based on the wording of the original post. @Themonkegamer can you confirm which haunt this is?

Comment: Spoiler -- Potential list of haunts using bloodstone: http://betrayalhouse.wikia.com/wiki/Haunt